# Limit meeting length for outlook calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016, meeting-request

We use a outlook calendar for planning a resource with outlook. 
The resource has an own active directory user and an outlook account.
Every colleague has the inbox added in his outlook as an additionally inbox and can directly add meetings in the calendar for the resource.

Is it possible to limit the meetings for this calendar, for example the colleagues can only insert meetings with maximum length of 2 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean resource mailbox, this can be set in EAC:
[image]

Reference: [Create and manage room mailboxes](http://C:%5CUsers%5Cv-panyu%5CDesktop%5CCreate%20and%20manage%20room%20mailboxes)

Duration limits cannot be set for user mailbox, currently.